# Quadratic Inequality - how do you solve this question?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

> $2x^{2} - \frac{27}{8}x - \frac{11}{3} \ge \frac{3}{27}x+ \frac{1}{12}$

Rearranging this equation and solving for x using the quadratic formula my answer is

> $x\ge \frac{1}{288} (251 + \sqrt{218521})$ or $x\le \frac{1}{288} (251 - \sqrt{218521})$

But the answer is said to be

> $x\ge \frac{5}{2}$ or $x\le \frac{-3}{4}$

Please can someone explain the solution

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*x%5E2-%2827%2F8%29*x-11%2F3%3E%3Dx%2F9%2B1%2F12) agrees with you.

Comment: Make sure you read the problem correctly. As is, your answer is correct and the given answer is wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Why would the question have $\frac3{27}$ rather than $\frac19$?

Answer (score 1):

There  must have been a typographical error.  The explanation of the solution given is that it is for

$$2x^{2} - \frac{27}{8}x - \frac{11}{3} \ge \frac{3}{2\color{red}4}x+ \frac{1}{12}.$$

Comment: Thank you, how did you identify this and correct it?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you have done is completely correct and you got the right answer. When you will solve the equation further by taking the square root you will get almost the same answer as it is given. The difference which you will get is very small so you can neglect it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much!